# Jqgrid is not able to add, edit or delete into my instance of SQL server and I don't think it is even hitting the add, edit or delete function

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, free-jqgrid

I am having issues with Free Jqgrid where I can not get it to post to my developer version of Microsoft SQL server. I am using Microsoft visual studios. I am using entity framework 6 for the database connections. When I use break points it doesn't seem to hit my createbid, editbid, or delete bid. I also don't get any errors in console.

I have looked through and done many of the tutorials for editing updating and adding lines. I had the same problem. I cant find an answer that works on stack overflow through my research.

I published it to IIS to see if maybe it was something with visual studios and to see if anything changes but i did get some errors this time. It is not finding the /Home/GetBidValues, Home/EditBid, /Home/CreateBid, /Home/DeleteBid. this is weird because with visual studios it was at least getting data into the grid and showing it. So I will look into this further and see if  there is something wrong with my ajax and also with my C# code.

Here is my Jquery file

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid
        ({
            url: "/Home/GetBidValues",
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'Get',  
            colNames: ['Client Cost', 'ElementId', 'Note', 'Area', 'Element', 'Item', 'Qty', 'Description'], //Othr Misc
            //colModel takes the data from controller and binds to grid   
            colModel: [
               {
                    key: true,
                    hidden: true,
                    name: 'ElementId',
                    index: 'ElementId',
                    frozen: true,
                    editable: false
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'Note',
                    index: 'Note',
                    frozen: true,
                    editable: true,
                    width: 70,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'Area',
                    index: 'Area',
                    frozen: true,
                    editable: true,
                    width: 70,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'Element',
                    index: 'Element',
                    frozen: true,
                    editable: true,
                    width: 70,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    name: 'Item',
                    index: 'Item',
                    frozen: true,
                    editable: true,
                    width: 70,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'QTY',
                    index: 'QTY',
                    frozen: true,
                    editable: true,
                    width: 70,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'Description',
                    index: 'Description',
                    frozen: true,
                    editable: true,
                    width: 70,
                    align: 'center'
                }],

            pager: '#pager',
            gridview: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            rowNumbers: false,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            height: '100%',
            width: 1000,
            viewrecords: true,
            footerrow: true,
            emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
            jsonReader:
            {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "0"
            }

        });
        $('#grid').jqGrid( 'inlineNav','#pager', {
            edit: true,
            add: true,
            del: true,
            cancel: true,
            search: true,
            refresh: true,
            editparams: {
                keys:true
            }
        }, {
            // edit options  
            zIndex: 100,
                url: '/Home/EditBid',
                //datatype: 'json',
                //mtype: 'Post',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            reloadaftersubmit: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },{//add
            zIndex: 100,
                url: "/Home/CreateBid",
            closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                reloadaftersubmit: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        }, {
            // delete options  
            zIndex: 100,
                url: "/Home/DeleteBid",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                reloadaftersubmit: true,
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Here is my C# file

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ERPWebAppTest.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;


namespace ERPWebAppTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {       
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        Test1Entities db = new Test1Entities();

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetBidValues(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows) 
        {
            //old code
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            var Results = db.BidDetails.Select(
                a => new
                {
                    a.ElementID,
                    a.Note ,
                    a.Area ,
                    a.Element ,
                    a.Item ,
                    a.QTY ,
                    a.Descr ,        
    });
            int totalRecords = Results.Count();
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
            if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
            {
                Results = Results.OrderByDescending(s => s.ElementID);
                Results = Results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            else
            {
                Results = Results.OrderBy(s => s.ElementID);
                Results = Results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = Results
            };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string CreateBid([Bind(Exclude = "ElementID")] BidDetail obj)
        {


            Test1Entities db = new Test1Entities();
            string msg;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.BidDetails.Add(obj);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    msg = "Saved Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "Validation data not successfully";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
            }

            return msg;


        }
        [HttpPost]
        public string EditBid(BidDetail obj)
        {
            Test1Entities db = new Test1Entities();
            string msg;

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    msg = "Saved Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "Validation data not successfull";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
            }

            return msg;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public string DeleteBid(int ElementID)
        {
            Test1Entities db = new Test1Entities();
            BidDetail list = db.BidDetails.Find(ElementID);
            db.BidDetails.Remove(list);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return "Deleted successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many small small issues into your jqgrid code, which can be one of the reason of your current problem. You can change them in order to make the above code workable.

- colModel items numbers are not exactly same as colNames items. You wrote `Client Cost` at first in colNames but in colModel you haven't used that.
- You also haven't pasted your html code which is required to point jqgrid to load on table element.
  for example: 
  `<table id="grid" class="table table-bordered"></table>
  <div id="pager"></div>`
- I am also assuming that you have already added free-jqgrid scripts and jquery-ui css files.
- Also, in your c# code you can remove redundancy by using a global db initialization.

I have created a demo jqgrid which you can alter according your requirement:

```
<div class="row">

<table id="grid" class="table table-bordered"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/free-jqGrid/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#grid").jqGrid
            ({
                url: "/Home/GetBidValues",
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'Get',
                colNames: ['LanguageId', 'LanguageName', 'LanguageDescription', 'CreatedBy', 'CreatedOn'], //Othr Misc
                //colModel takes the data from controller and binds to grid
                colModel: [
                    //{ name: "act", template: "actions", align: "left", width: 58 },
                   {
                       key: true,
                       hidden: true,
                       name: 'LanguageId',
                       index: 'LanguageId',

                       editable: false
                   }, {
                       key: false,
                       name: 'LanguageName',
                       index: 'LanguageName',
                       frozen: true,
                       editable: true,

                       align: 'center'
                   }, {
                       key: false,
                       name: 'LanguageDescription',
                       index: 'LanguageDescription',

                       editable: true,

                       align: 'center'
                   }, {
                       key: false,
                       name: 'CreatedBy',
                       index: 'CreatedBy',

                       editable: true,

                       align: 'center'
                   }, {
                       name: 'CreatedOn',
                       index: 'CreatedOn',

                       editable: true,

                       align: 'center'
                   }],
                //cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true },
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                rowNum: 10,
                //autoResizing: { compact: true },
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
                viewrecords: true,
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                toppager: false,
                inlineEditing: { keys: true, position: "afterSelected" },
                rownumbers: true,
                sortname: "invdate",
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "Demonstration of the usage custom action buttons",
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                jsonReader:
                {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    Id: "LanguageId"
                }

            });
        jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: 
false, defaultSearch: "cn", multipleSearch: true, searchOperators: true, search: true 
});        //searchOnEnter: false means records are filtered as soon as the text is 
entered by the user
        jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true,view:true }, {
            // edit options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: '/Home/EditBid',
            //datatype: 'json',
            //mtype: 'Post',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            reloadaftersubmit: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        }, {//add
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/Home/CreateBid",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            reloadaftersubmit: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        }, {
            // delete options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/Home/DeleteBid",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            reloadaftersubmit: true,
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

}
```